# Block reward transaction number in block

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

When a new block is mined, new coins are minted and given to the miner as a reward. The transaction in which this reward is transferred to the miner is included in the same block? If yes, then that transaction is added in the end of the block, or in the start, or in the middle somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific blockchain.

For example in Bitcoin, the coinbase transaction (creating the reward to the miner; the exchange name is inspired by this term) needs to be the first transaction of the block.

While in PoW Ethereum, the miner address is "just" a property of the raw block object. Which is sufficient by the rules of the network to increase the address `value` (by a reward amount again specified by the network), without any specific transaction.

See this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/386) pointing out pros and cons of both approaches.

Comment: So you mean the reward transaction in Ethereum isn't added to the transaction ledger?

Comment: @USMANFAZIL In case of Ethereum, there's no reward transaction. The ETH is automatically funded to the miner address without a transaction.